# How can you create a list and remove an item from the list in one line?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let's say we have

```
df = pd.Dataframe(columns = ['item', 'item1', 'item2'])
```

and I want to create a list of the columns without one element. I would like to do something like

`df.columns.remove('item2')` but such code simply return 'None". Meanwhile,

```
l = list(df.columns)
l.remove('item2')
```

works fine. Is there a way to distill this code into one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.difference`:

```py
print(df.columns.difference(["item2"]))
```

Prints:

```
Index(['item', 'item1'], dtype='object')
```

---

Or a list output:

```py
print(df.columns.difference(["item2"]).tolist())
```

Prints:

```
['item', 'item1']
```